# would eclipse recognise drawable-xxhdpi folder?

Tags: android

Greeting,

I have attempted to add a xxhdpi folder under the res. When I tested on 1080X1920 emulator, why eclipse loads the images where I was placed in drawable-xhdpi (720X1080)?

Comment: have you check in eclipse editor view how it looks ?

Answer (score 1):

The screen resolution is not indicative of the pixel density. Think of tablets. Lots of pixels, but only MDPI~HDPI pixel density.

In other words, it's using XHDPI graphics because the emulator is emulating an XHDPI device.

Answer (score 1):

Actually no need to add any graphics for XXHDPI it will pick from XHDPI and auto scale it.

public static final int DENSITY_XXHIGH

```
Added in API level 16
```

Standard quantized DPI for extra-extra-high-density screens. Applications should not generally worry about this density; relying on XHIGH graphics being scaled up to it should be sufficient for almost all cases.

```
Constant Value: 480 (0x000001e0)
```

in rare care you can also use `drawable-xxhdpi or drawable-480dpi` folder to place app icon with `144 x 144 px`

if you see your android-sdk folder at this below location

```
/home/padmakumar/android-sdk/platforms/android-17/data/res/mipmap-xxhdpi
```

there you can see an icon `sym_def_app_icon.png` with `144 x 144px`

Comment: If you want your users to actually get a benefit from having an XXHDPI screen, you better provide XXHDPI resources. Otherwise your app won't look any better than it does on an XHDPI screen (actually it will look slightly worse, because of blurring).