# Create Different layout for galaxy s4

Tags: android

Galaxy s4

Screen: 5.0", 1920x1080 (~441 ppi pixel density).

Which the res folder would be used in FHD and what's the dpi value should be set?

Comment: would eclipse recognise drawable-xxhdpi folder? http://stackoverflow.com/a/17060758/1012284

Answer (score 0):

i think dpi value is `441` and that means `xxhdpi` folder used for layout..

Answer (score 0):

That would fit into xxhdpi at 441dpi according to the [android developers](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/D4qjK4HLX9u) (see comments in that thread)